# Find out if a number is present in an array of arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays

I want to return true if the number 2 is contained in this array of arrays. How can I do this using javascript? This is an example of my array of arrays:

```
[
  [1, "Canteen" ],
  [2, "Swift Room"]
]
```

I have been trying something like the following:

```
const isBooked = slotsForDate.map((val) => {
    if (val.includes(slot.id)) {
        return true;
    }
});
```

But I have had no luck yet.

Comment: well that will return an array, not a single boolean since that is what map does. You want [`some()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some)

Comment: Not with `.map()`... If `true` or `false` is enough then have a look at `.some()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another way would be to flatten the nested array with [`Array.flat()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat), then call [`Array.includes()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) on the return. Probably the shortest code:

```js
const isBooked = slotsForDate.flat().includes(slot.id);
```

Answer (score 4):

You can try using [`Array.prototype.some()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) like the following way:

```js
const slotsForDate = [
  [
    1,
    "Canteen"
  ],
  [
    2,
    "Swift Room"
  ]
]

const isBooked = slotsForDate.some(val => val.includes(2));
console.log(isBooked);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a brute force approach to help you understand the logic.

```js
const checkArr = (check) => {
  for(let i=0; i<arr.length; i++){
    for(let j=0; j<arr[i].length; j++){
      if(arr[i][j] === check){
        //return true here
        console.log(arr[i][j]);
      }
    }
  }
  //return false here
}

let arr = [
      [
        1,
        "Canteen"
      ],
      [
        2,
        "Swift Room"
      ]
    ]
    

let checkValue = 2;

checkArr(checkValue);
```

Answer (score 0):

This recursive function works for nested arrays no matter how many levels of arrays there are. It goes through each item of an array and check if target is there:

```js
const ar = [[1,"Canteen"],
            [2,"Swift Room"]];

function searchElement(a, target, index = 0) {
  if (index >= a.length)  
    return false;

  return (Array.isArray(a[index]) ? searchElement(a[index], target) :
                                    a[index] === target) 
         || searchElement(a, target, index + 1);
}

console.log(
  searchElement(ar, 2)
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Despite [my other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68818250/2114313) being marked as accepted, I think the way the problem is stated may not be the safest way.

If that were my code, I would investigate just the first item of each array that forms the inner elements of the main/outer array. Because I only want to match the **slot identifier**, not a **slot description** that may be the same as (some other slot's) identifier.

I would do that via something like:

```js
const slotID = 2;
const isBooked = slotsForDate.some(slot => slot[0] === slotId);
```

In general IMHO, data structure design is probably as important as algorithm design, the more so now that the programming world (including JavaScript) moves toward a Functional Programming paradigm. In this endeavour it helps to be clear (and state clearly when communicating with others) what the different parts of a data structure mean, and to state problems (even if to yourself) in the more abstract meaning ("I want to see if a slot exists with the given ID") instead of the more concrete implementation details ("Is there a 2 somewhere in the data structure?"). Then when implementing the solution, it should reflect the abstract intention, which will cause less unintended bugs and better readability/understandability to a later maintainer.

---

Further musings:

A data structure that would capture the intent of the system better would be something like the below. Although one can not always argue with what is supplied by legacy or third-party components...

```
const slotsForDate = [
  {id: 1, desc: 'Canteen'},
  {id: 2, desc: 'Swift room'}
]
```

The following should also be possible (taking the JS object convention to **implicitly** state the key/id and the value/description:

```
const slotsForDate = {
  1: 'Canteen',
  2: 'Swift room'
}
```

which then translates to a (sparse) array - **provided the ID is strictly numeric**, it can now be implicitly used as the array index:

```
const slotsForDate = [ undefined, 'Canteen', 'Swift room' ]
```

Where checking if a slot is booked is as simple as:

```
const slotID = 2;
const isBooked = !!slotsForDate[slotId];
```

Answer (score -1):

```
const slotsForDate = [
  [
    1,
    "Canteen"
  ],
  [
    2,
    "Swift Room"
  ]
];

function check(n){
    let find = false;
    slotsForDate.forEach(element => {
        if (element[0] === n){
            find = true;
        }
    });
return find;
}

console.log(check(2));
```

Comment: It will work (at least if `n` is always in the first element of the nested array), but isn't very efficient because the `forEach` will keep looping, even after the element has already been found.